# Xamarin Forms LocalNotification not showing when button clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am a novice in Xamarin Forms, I am trying to show a local notification whenever a button is clicked.

I have installed this plugin:
-https://github.com/B1naryStudio/Xamarin.LocalNotifications
-https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.LocalNotifications/

The thing is, the plugin does not work. I have followed every step but I cannot see why I still have nothing.

Here my XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LeafWords.Classes.SettingsLeaf.WordSettings">
    <ContentPage.Content>


        <StackLayout>
            <Button Clicked="WordNotif" Text="Local Notification"></Button>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is my method:

```
  void WordNotif() {

        // Handle when your app starts
        var notification = new LocalNotification
        {
            Text = "Hello Plugin",
            Title = "Nbation Plugin",
            Id = 2,
            NotifyTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)
        };

        var notifier = CrossLocalNotifications.CreateLocalNotifier();
        notifier.Notify(notification);

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local notification Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771136/local-notification-xamarin-forms)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis the topic is different

Comment: I don't see you try at button click, I see it in constructor. Do you wait 10 seconds? What platform you are testing on?

Comment: if it's Android did you add <receiver android:name="localnotifications.plugin.ScheduledAlarmHandler" android:enabled="true"></receiver>

Comment: @YuriS for the moment I do my test on android

Comment: Yes I have added this

Comment: did you install plugin on ALL platforms?

Comment: yes I have done it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148172/discussion-between-hugo-and-yuri-s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the setup section of the LocalNotifications Github page, the code there alone will not work, you need to add the SET_ALARM permission to your Android manifest.

Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```

Here's what the final version should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
  <application android:label="Notification.Android">
    <receiver android:name="localnotifications.plugin.ScheduledAlarmHandler" android:enabled="true"></receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I tested this with the code you posted and it works well.

[Working Code](https://github.com/kojanabzah/xamarinForms.Notification)

Comment: Thanks I have tried it but it is still not working, can show me your class please

Comment: hi @hugo, have you confirmed  WordNotif function is getting called?  can you change it to "void WordNotif(object sender, EventArgs e){....}" ?

Comment: void WordNotif(object sender, EventArgs e ) {

            // Handle when your app starts
            var notification = new LocalNotification
            {
                Text = "Hello Plugin",
                Title = "Nbation Plugin",
                Id = 2,

                NotifyTime = DateTime.Now
            };

            var notifier = CrossLocalNotifications.CreateLocalNotifier();
            notifier.Notify(notification);

          

        }

Comment: Pushed the code to github and added the link to the answer.

Comment: All looks fine on the files you pushed to your git, i will need to have project to run on my side to see why its not working , if you dont want to share more code can you create smaller version of your project and push it to git so i can run it ?

Comment: Here is a smal version of the project:https://github.com/kisebwe/localnotif

Comment: @hugo, the code you uploaded to github works as expected , you had a small typo there where you added 's'  to var notification = new LocalNotifications  and it need to be LocalNotification (without s ) but i guess its just a copy paste mistake , other then that when i click the button i get a notification, tested on actual device + emulator .

Comment: I do not understand , I am using an emulator and I cannot see a notification.

Comment: I am using android 7 , Nexus 10, where I am suppose to see notification, because on the top of the screen  I have "no notifications"

Comment: (I am an Iphone user)

Comment: did you check only on emulator ?  do you see the notification on the iphone ? [notification image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycCqo.png)

Comment: I have checked but nothing like on your screen

Comment: I cannot debug on Iphone I am working on window and I have not a mac

Comment: Can you try downloading the local notifications code from  github and running there sample ? The xamarin forms and android only project .

Comment: Very strange, what vs version are you using? And what android version are you using on the emulator ? Dont think its related but you never know

Comment: I am using : device : nexus 10   target :android 7.1.1  cpu/ABI : Google API intel Atom   (x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

I found this link , and it is working :
https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin